# Ionic And Angular 5 form builders and groups is not reading values

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, formbuilder

I am learning ionic with angular.

I created a login form:

```
<form [formGroup]="login">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>
        <ion-icon android="android-contacts" name="contacts"></ion-icon>
      </ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" value="" name="username" [formControlName]="'username'" ></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>
        <ion-icon android="android-unlock" md="md-unlock"></ion-icon>
      </ion-label>
      <ion-input type="password" value="" name="password" [formControlName]="'password'" placeholder="Password"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </form>
  <button ion-button full (click)="onLoginClick()" [disabled]="login.valid" >LOGIN</button>
```

And here I declared the form group with controls:

```
constructor(public fb: FormBuilder, public authService: ApiAuthProvider, public altCtrl: AlertController, public navCtrl: NavController, 

    public navParams: NavParams) {

    this.login = fb.group({
      username: new FormControl(['u', Validators.required]),
      password: new FormControl(['p', Validators.required])
    })
  }
```

There is no error at `ionic serve`, but the login button is not disbaled, and can't read what I typed in username input when I click on the login button:

```
onLoginClick(){
    console.log(this.login['username']);
}
```

It always display `undefined` as result.

By the way, working with form builders in ionic is the same when working with a pure Angular app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to access form control value like

```
onLoginClick(){
    console.log(this.login.get('username').value);
}
```

And also you are trying to disable it when form is valid. You should check for invalid

```
<button ion-button full (click)="onLoginClick()" [disabled]="login.invalid" >LOGIN</button>
```

EDIT :

Modify form control parameters this way : You are passing them as an array. They should be two separate parameters.

```
this.login = fb.group({
      username: new FormControl('u', Validators.required),
      password: new FormControl('p', Validators.required)
})
```

You may add array of validators if you have multiple validators like

`new FormControl('u', [Validators.required, Validators.maxlength])`

Comment: but if you notice in the declaration I set the username input to display `u`, but it is not showing on the form.

Comment: And I fixed the button validation, but still not working. So if I typed inside 2 inputs, the button will stay disabled

Comment: Now is working fine, except of `u` is not showing inside the textbox

Comment: What do you mean by `except of u is not showing inside the textbox`? Have you modified your form control params as per updated answer?

Comment: Here `new FormControl('u', Validators.required)`, `u` is not showing inside the input

Comment: Remove `value=""` attribute. It should work fine. Check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formcontrol-amit?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value of the form using

`this.login.value`;

If your are using this in the html do like this.

`{{login.value | json}}`

Or you can get value of a specifica control using\

`this.login.get('controlName).value;`

Comment: I fixed the button validation, but still not working. So if I typed inside 2 inputs, the button will stay disabled

Comment: can you add a `console.log(this.login.errors)` inside the submit method and give me the output?